# Spritekit and swiftui, change scene a better way

Tags: swift, swiftui, sprite-kit, scene

I wrote this simple few line of code to swap between 2 scene in Swiftui using SpriteKit, I'm try to understand if there could be a (better) different way to change from one scene to another using a button.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var firstscene = FirstScene()
    @StateObject var secondscene = SecondScene()
    @State var changeScene = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            
            if changeScene {
                SpriteView(scene: firstscene)
            } else {
                SpriteView(scene: secondscene)
            }
            
            Button {
                changeScene.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Change")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// the 2 SKScene created using a sub class of SKscene

```
class FirstScene: SKScene, ObservableObject {
    let firstScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "FirstScene")
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        scene?.view?.presentScene(firstScene)
    }
    
}
class SecondScene: SKScene, ObservableObject {
    let secondScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "SecondScene")
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        scene?.view?.presentScene(secondScene)
    }
}
```

now my doubt is, I'm change the SpriteView in the contentView using a var changeScene, could be done the same things in some other way using another approach?

open to any suggestions, I'm try to understand this framework .

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a standard way of switching views. You could clean your code up a bit like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var changeScene = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
                SpriteView(scene: (changeScene ? FirstScene() : SecondScene())) // this is a terniary operator 
        
            Button {
                changeScene.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Change")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The new views do not need to be @StateObjects. You can call the View Types directly in your view.

Note: I am away from my computer so this is not tested.

Comment: This isn't working for me. Have you tested this recently?
`class Scene1: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        size = view.frame.size
        scaleMode = .resizeFill
        addChild(SKLabelNode(text: "Game"))
    }
}`

`class Scene2: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        size = view.frame.size
        scaleMode = .resizeFill
        addChild(SKLabelNode(text: "GameOver"))
    }
}`

Comment: I am not sure you have your scenes set up properly. Your best bet is to ask a new question with a minimal reproducible example. But make sure each of your scenes are set up correctly. The basic premise still works. You just need to return the same type from the ternary.

Comment: It seems like there is a similar problem in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69610165/spriteview-doesnt-pause-scene-on-state-change. Before I post a full question for this could you confirm that the ternary operator is working on your system?

Comment: No, because I do not have working code to test it with, and I am not going to write a testable MRE.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 14, Swift 5

This is tested and comes from this article.

https://betterprogramming.pub/build-a-game-of-chess-with-spritekit-3229c23bdba0

import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var switcher = false

var scene: SKScene {
    let scene = GameScene.shared
    scene.size = CGSize(width: 256, height: 512)
    scene.scaleMode = .fill
    scene.backgroundColor = .red
    scene.name = "red"
    return scene
}

var scene2: SKScene {
    let scene2 = GameScene2.shared
    scene2.size = CGSize(width: 256, height: 512)
    scene2.scaleMode = .fill
    scene2.backgroundColor = .blue
    scene2.name = "blue"
    
    return scene2
}

var body: some View {
  if switcher {
    SpriteView(scene: scene)
        .frame(width: 256, height: 512)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .background(Color.red)
        .onAppear {
          scene2.isPaused = true
        }
        .onDisappear {
          scene2.isPaused = false
        }
        
  } else {
    SpriteView(scene: scene2)
        .frame(width: 256, height: 512)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .background(Color.blue)
        .onAppear {
          scene.isPaused = true
          
        }
        .onDisappear {
          scene.isPaused = false
        }
        
  }
  Button {
    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)) {
      switcher.toggle()
    }
  } label: {
    Text("play")
  }
  
}
}
```