# How to detect touch in SpriteKit if using a scene load from editor

Tags: swift, swiftui, sprite-kit, scenekit, gesture

i created 2 subclass of SKScene called FirstScene and SecondScene, the FirstScene load a scene from an sks file and present it, second one create a scene by code with red background.

```
class FirstScene: SKScene, ObservableObject {
    let firstScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "FirstScene")
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        scene?.view?.presentScene(firstScene)
        scene?.scaleMode = .resizeFill
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("touch")
    }
    
}
```

```
class SecondScene: SKScene, ObservableObject {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        backgroundColor = .black
        self.size = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        scene?.scaleMode = .fill
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("touch")
        
    }
}
```

i don't know why I can't detect the touch from the FirstScene... why touchesMoved only work in the secondScene ?? Something I'm missing?

thanks

Comment: What does 'scene?.view?.presentScene(firstScene)' do?  What is 'isUserInteractionEnabled = true' for?

Comment: present the scene from sks file into the scene loaded, without that line of code the scene is a white empty scene

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't make sense as far as `SKScene` is concerned.  You are not adding firstScene to FirstScene.  You are covering `SKView` with it.

Comment: sorry, I'm just start to understand SpriteKit, I'm try to change the scene load from sks file using a button, and detect a touch in each scene.  here my previous question, where I post the code I use to load the to sks file, my be is wrong? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68784060/spritekit-and-swiftui-change-scene-a-better-way/68784445#68784445

Comment: how can I load an sks file into a custom class? in swiftUI I can load directly in the view let customScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "FirstScene") and present it with SpriteView(scene: firstscene) but I would like to load it using a custom class in order to work with it

Comment: Explain what you are trying to do instead of asking why your app doesn't work as expected by looking at the code.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 14, Swift 5

This except from an article I posted on medium defines two scenes and lets you switch between them. Does this do what you want to do?

https://betterprogramming.pub/build-a-game-of-chess-with-spritekit-3229c23bdba0

```
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit

struct ContentView: View {

@State var switcher = false

var scene: SKScene {
    let scene = GameScene.shared
    scene.size = CGSize(width: 256, height: 512)
    scene.scaleMode = .fill
    scene.backgroundColor = .red
    scene.name = "red"

    return scene
}

var scene2: SKScene {
    let scene2 = GameScene2.shared
    scene2.size = CGSize(width: 256, height: 512)
    scene2.scaleMode = .fill
    scene2.backgroundColor = .blue
    scene2.name = "blue"
    
    return scene2
}

var body: some View {
  if switcher {
    SpriteView(scene: scene)
        .frame(width: 256, height: 512)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .background(Color.red)
        .onAppear {
          scene2.isPaused = true
        }
        .onDisappear {
          scene2.isPaused = false
        }
        
  } else {
    SpriteView(scene: scene2)
        .frame(width: 256, height: 512)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .background(Color.blue)
        .onAppear {
          scene.isPaused = true
          
        }
        .onDisappear {
          scene.isPaused = false
        }
        
  }
  Button {
    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)) {
      switcher.toggle()
    }
  } label: {
    Text("play")
  }
  
}
}
```